# Add LaTeX 'tags' to include/exclude sections of Markdown from command line

Tags: sectioning, pdftex, templates, pandoc, markdown

I would like to be able to "turn on/off" certain sections of my documents, depending on a command line declaration.

I am converting a large group of policy documents that are for both internal and external use, via Pandoc, to PDF, using a LaTeX template, and Pandoc is using pdfTeX. I also have a PowerShell script that converts them recursively.

```
gci -r -i *.md | foreach{$pdf=$_.directoryname+"\"+$_.basename+".pdf"; pandoc -f markdown --template template.latex -V geometry:margin=1.5cm -V fontfamily:lato -V fontfamilyoptions:default -V fontfamilyoptions:defaultsans -s $_.name -o $pdf}
```

External versions don't need the document details section, which is the first page after the table of contents. I could probably remove the third page, but there are some documents with long ToC's, and some without, besides which, it doesn't strike me as a an elegant solution.

My typical document looks something like this (YAML and content reduced for brevity):

```
---
title: "A policy"
documentdetails: True/false % I could add something here for the default?
...

Table of contents:

\documentdetailstart % A tag looking like this for instance

# Document Details

#### Document Details

| Description | Status/Version | Reference Code | Control |
| --- |---|---|---|
|A Policy | Final / 1.0 | LaTeX | All |

\documentdetailend % A tag looking like this for instance

Begin Document
```

How can I add some kind of wrapping to the markdown of each policy, that is dealt with in the template perhaps, so that I can add something like the below on the command line to automatically omit/include the contents of the tag.

```
-V Documentdetails:True
```

Thanks in advance for any assistance you can provide!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could have an

```
\iftrue
Document details
\fi
```

and tell your powershell script to replace iftrue with iffalse and compile a new copy.

Edit:
If you surround all the internal only stuff with `\begininternal` and `\endinternal` as below, then you can toggle between whether the document is for an internal or an external copy of the pdf by replacing `iffalse` with `iftrue` on the second line.
Then you just need to get your script to say "if external, replace iffalse with iftrue and compile" or somesuch.

```
\documentclass{article}
\let\begininternal\iffalse
\let\endinternal\fi

\begin{document}
Stuff everyone gets

\begininternal
Internal  only stuff
\endinternal

More stuff everyone gets

\begininternal
More internal only stuff
\endinternal

The end.
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Hi Fintan, thanks for your reply, I'm quite new to LaTeX and I was wondering if you could provide a little more detail about how I would go about this. Each of the documents has a # Document Details heading, so are you saying I should tell it to exclude that specific heading? Or do I need to amend the template&markdown in some way to allow this?

Comment: Apologies - I've edited my response and elaborated a little. Hopefully that makes things clearer. If I've misunderstood what you're trying to do, please let me know.

Comment: That's fantastic, It was just the \let\begininternal\iffalse part that I didn't know how to add. This works perfectly. I guess I could just have two templates, one with true, and one with false. I imagine the -V in powershell bit is the 'proper' way, but probably for a separate question/further research on my part - unless you have any ideas? Many thanks for your help though, I'll mark this as answered!